# how to default a value for non existing node in xslt

Tags: xslt, default-value

I have following xml element in the source and would like to map to an element in the target.

Whenever there is no node in the source, I want to default it to a string "None"

--------------------------Source XML----------------------------------------------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Instructions  InstructionType="Gen">Some Message</Instructions>
<Instructions  InstructionType="Test">Some Other Message</Instructions>
```

---------------------------Transformation XSL--------------------------------------

```
<xsl:if test='/ns1:OrderResponse/ns1:OrderResponseBody/ns1:OrderResponseProperties/ns1:Instructions/@InstructionType = "Gen"'>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test='/ns1:OrderResponse/ns1:OrderResponseBody/ns1:OrderResponseProperties/ns1:Instructions[@InstructionType = "Gen"] != ""'>
            <ns0:siGen>
                <xsl:value-of select='substring(/ns1:OrderResponse/ns1:OrderResponseBody/ns1:OrderResponseProperties/ns1:Instructions[@InstructionType = "Gen"],1.0,199.0)'/>
            </ns0:siGen>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="not(/ns1:OrderResponse/ns1:OrderResponseBody/ns1:OrderResponseProperties/ns1:Instructions[@InstructionType = 'Gen'])">
            <ns0:siGen>
                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="no">None</xsl:text>
            </ns0:siGen>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <ns0:siGen>
                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="no">None</xsl:text>
            </ns0:siGen>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:if>
```

---------------------------------------------Issue-------------------------------------------------------------

When the source xml doesn't have the the node at all as shown below (commented), I cannot default the value "None" to the target element "ns0:siGen"

```
<!--Instructions  InstructionType="Gen">Some Message</Instructions-->

<Instructions  InstructionType="Test">Some Other Message</Instructions>
```

---

I dont understand why the below condition is not working:

```
<xsl:when test="not(/ns1:OrderResponse/ns1:OrderResponseBody/ns1:OrderResponseProperties/ns1:Instructions[@InstructionType = 'Gen'])">
```

Please advise.

Thanks

Yogi

Comment: Is it a typo that your source xml says `Instructions` but your xslt is checking for `SpecialInstructions[@InstructionType = 'Gen'])`?

Comment: yes, its a typo, I just corrected it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very first line in your XSLT sample says this...

```
<xsl:if   
     test='/ns1:OrderResponse/ns1:OrderResponseBody/ns1:OrderResponseProperties/ns1:Instructions/@InstructionType = "Gen"'>
```

i.e. You are testing if there is an **Instructions** element which has an **InstructionType** equal to "Gen". So, obviously if you comment this **Instructions** element, the statement will be false, and so your **xsl:choose** inside the statement will not be executed.

To simplify things, consider putting the **instructions** element in a variable

```
<xsl:variable name="gen" 
              select="ns1:OrderResponse/ns1:OrderResponseBody/ns1:OrderResponseProperties/ns1:Instructions[@InstructionType = 'Gen']" />
```

Then you can have a simple **xsl:choose** to test this

```
 <ns0:siGen>
    <xsl:choose>
       <xsl:when test="$gen != ''"><xsl:value-of select="$gen" /></xsl:when>
       <xsl:otherwise>None</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
 <ns0:siGen>
```